# cake php paginator and ajax - how I can invoke function before ajax request?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am using paginator with ajax:

```
$this->Paginator->options(array(
    'update' => '#content',
    'evalScripts' => true
));
```

And it works fine, but just before sending ajax request (for example when user clicks next page) I would like to show some 'loading' information on site. Is there any option to set some callback (javascript function) in paginator?

Comment: Have you tried the 'beforeSend' key?

Comment: Perfect, thanks! I thought about it but this option is missing in paginator documentation...

Comment: I added it as an answer if you'd be so kind to accept so people see its resolved. Glad it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Since the PaginatorHelper uses the JsHelper to create the link when it detects the 'update' key, you can use all keys relating to the JsHelper's link and request functions.

```
$this->Paginator->options(array(
    'update' => '#content',
    'evalScripts' => true,
    'beforeSend' => // do js stuff here
));
```